# How to associate all textbox controls on a form with the same event handler

Tags: vb.net

VB 2008.

I have several text boxes on a form and I want each of them to use the same event handler. I know how to manually wire each one up to the handler, but I'm looking for a more generic way so if I add more text boxes they will automatically be hooked up to the event handler.

Ideas?

EDIT: Using the C# sample from MusiGenesis (and with the help of the comment left by nick), I wrote this VB code:

```
Private Sub AssociateTextboxEventHandler()
  For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
      AddHandler c.TextChanged, AddressOf tb_TextChanged
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot! SO is great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do something like this in your form's load event (C#, sorry, but it's easy to translate):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
        }
    }

}

void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.Tag = "CHANGED"; // or whatever
}
```

It's not properly recursive (it won't find text boxes on panels, for example), but you get the idea.

Comment: In VB.NET, the equivolent to += on an event is to use AddHandler

Answer (score 3):

"c As Control" has no "TextChanged" event, so it will throw an error.
You may optimize that to Linq and also get rid of that error with:

```
For Each c As TextBox In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    AddHandler c.TextChanged, AddressOf tb_TextChanged
Next
```

But that would avoid to go deeper than first level thou.

Comment: There is no error because I check the type of the control (`If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then`) before adding the `TextChanged` handler.

Comment: You're completely right. But for no apparent reason, when I added that code to my testing app it throwed the error.

Answer (score 2):

You could recursively iterate over the Controls collection in the OnLoad of the form and assign the event handler to any text boxes you find.

Comment: I would love to see the code to do this in VB.NET.  This kind of thing is very easy in Delphi, but I've not seen a clear way to do it in VB.NET yet.

Comment: For Each c as control in me.controls
if typeof c is textbox 
c.addhandler c.textchanged, addressof textboxhandler
end if
next

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible with a macro, but otherwise, I a m not aware of anything that would automatically wire an control to a generic handler.

The only easy way I know of would be to select all appliciable textboxes, and simply set the eventhandler for the click event at the same time, but that isn't automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will update all text controls:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    UpdateControls(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateControls(ByVal myControlIN As Control)
    Dim myControl

    For Each myControl In myControlIN.Controls
        UpdateControls(myControl)
        Dim myTextbox As TextBox

        If TypeOf myControl Is TextBox Then
            myTextbox = myControl
            AddHandler myTextbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_TextChanged
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox("text changed in " & CType(sender, TextBox).Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: You could say "If myControl.HasChildren Then UpdateControls(myControl)".

Answer (score 0):

I have many Textboxes inside many GroupBoxes inside a TabPage-Control.

To add/define/delete the Handler of those Textboxes i had to iterate first through the Tabpages, then through the Groupboxes in every Tabpage and then i can access the Textboxes inside these Groupboxes.

```
' cycle through TabPages ...
For Each page As TabPage In Me.TabControl1.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
    ' in every TabPage cycle through Groupboxes ...
    For Each gbox As GroupBox In page.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()
        ' and in every TextBox inside the actual GroupBox
        For Each tbox As TextBox In gbox.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            AddHandler tbox.TextChanged, AddressOf _TextChanged
        Next
    Next
Next

Private Sub _TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    somethingWasChanged = True
End Sub
```