# Assigning event TextChanged to all textboxes in Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Hello I was wondering how can I keep an eye on all `textboxes` in Form whether in any of them was changed value. I saw some code  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179742/how-to-associate-all-textbox-controls-on-a-form-with-the-same-event-handler)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
        }
    }
}

void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.Tag = "CHANGED"; // or whatever
}
```

And a guy who wrote this code says that "it can't be assigned to textboxes in Panels and Grouboxes".

So my question is as I have almost every textbox in groubox or panel, how can I see whether change was made for textboxes in panels or groupbox?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I think the only reason it will not work is because you are not iterating the children of `this.Controls`. I.e. Form -> Panel -> TextBox so you need to make your loop recursive and check all children of children etc to check all Text Boxes on the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make your method recursive:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Assign(this);
}

void Assign(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
        }
        else
        {
            Assign(ctrl);
        }
    }
}

void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.Tag = "CHANGED"; // or whatever
}
```

Just find a better name for the method instead of `Assign`.

Answer (score 3):

When you have to deal with nested controls, 1 for loop can't help. You have to use some recursive method or custom `stack` to loop through all the controls, something like this:

```
private void RegisterTextChangedEventHandler(Control root){
   Stack<Control> stack = new Stack<Control>();
   stack.Push(root);  
   Control current = null;     
   while(stack.Count>0){
      current = stack.Pop();
      foreach(var c in current.Controls){
         if(c is TextBox) ((TextBox)c).TextChanged += textChanged;
         stack.Push(c);
      }
   }
}
private void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //....
}
//Use it
RegisterTextChangedEventHandler(yourForm);//Or your container ....
```

Comment: Think this might need a slight tweak because you are only pushing children onto stack if the child is a TextBox whereas you only want to push if it is **NOT** a TextBox? Other than that, very clean code / implemented!

Comment: @Belogix Thanks, a little mistake. In fact, I also want to allow to push `TextBox` into the stack, otherwise use an `else` is OK, just updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need another loop for the `groupbox` and `panels`, you can use this code:

```
private void addEvents(Control.ControlCollection ct)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in ct)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
        }
        else if (ctrl is GroupBox || ctrl is Panel) addEvents(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addEvents(this.Controls);
}

void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.Tag = "CHANGED"; // or whatever
}
```